# how to validate email address domain using preg match

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

i want to validate the email address domain using pregmatch. also the valid edu domain i inserted in email list array so when user enter the email address that entry first check in email list array. if it is available then it is validate. i am doing validation part on server side.. any help is appericiated. thanks in advanced...

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email']; // get the email value
$email_exp = explode("@",$email); // split email 
$email_name = $email_exp[1]; // get the domain of email address

$email_list = array("berkely.edu","ucfs.edu","udef.edu","ucms.edu","ucef.edu"); // valid edu domain 

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($email_list);$i++)
{
if(in_array($email_name,$email_list))
{
if (preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/', $email_name))
{
  // validate email 
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why not [**`filter_var($email_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`**](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: if am using filter_var i don't need preg_match here.. ?? @stoic

Comment: @stoic i also need specific edu domain from listed in arrray so FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL replace from my email_list array... ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter_var`, and replace the `preg_match` call with it.

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == TRUE) {
   // email is valid
}
```

So, the updated code will be:

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email']; // get the email value
$email_exp = explode("@",$email); // split email 
$email_name = $email_exp[1]; // get the domain of email address
$email_list = array("berkely.edu","ucfs.edu","udef.edu","ucms.edu","ucef.edu");

$email_is_valid = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == TRUE;
if($email_is_valid && in_array($email_name,$email_list) ) {
  // email is valid for your purposes
}
```

Comment: after using filter_var i don't need the preg match here... ??

Comment: exactly. `filter_var` validates the email for you, and therefore, there is no need for `preg_match`

Comment: user enter email domain also checking in email list array .. if it is available in it then it's validate... FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL REPLACE FROM  my $email_list

Comment: @prashant: updated the answer with the correct code.

Comment: ok i am replace the code that u provide me.. and checked it's result...

Comment: it throw me 500 internal server error don't know why... ???

Comment: @prashant there was an extra `)` at the `$email_is_valid` line, check again the above example and compare with yours.

Comment: i don't know why we use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL WHAT it's actual working.. because my actual requirement is checking that user enter the email i am checkin in my list_array that no of edu domain i want to validate.... if i passed in_array parameter only in if condition then only it working for me... @prix

Comment: my actual question was how to validate edu domain using preg match and my register edu domain is specific that i am inserted into one array list.... if u saw my original code  i used the preg_match.... my validation is server side... so can i implement using preg_match for my register edu domain @prix..

Comment: @prashant Stoic's answer does exactly what you said, it will check the email is a valid email and then check if it ends with one of the given domains you have on your array. If you want to know more about what filter_var does, you can read it on the link link I have posted on the comments of your question.